# Signing modified system applications?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, apk, adt, sign

I'm modifing some apks of my Honeycomb Tablet. I added some functions to SystemUI.apk which require new permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file. The problem is that I need to re-sign the package with the system certificates. 
I tried to copy the META-INF from the previous apk, but the logcat is still saying "Invalid certificates". 
So I was wondering how can I do this..thanks in advance for any help.
PS: I already tried to sign the apk with my keystore, but still the same error.

Comment: Without having the original certificate you're out of luck (would be big security hole otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have access to the private key originally used to sign the APK, this is not possible.  Simply copying the META-INF does not work, as the signatures contained in those files are no longer correct.

Alternatively, you would have to rebuild the entire Android system, signing everything with your own private key — however this is currently not possible as the source code for Honeycomb is not available.

Comment: Copying META-INF worked with previously. But they didn't touch the Androidmanifest.xml. What about signing all the apks in system and framework with a new key?

Comment: Copying META-INF would only work if no files were changed at all; that includes `AndroidManifest.xml` and `classes.dex`. Re-signing every APK on the system may work; though I'm not sure if framework JARs and ODEX files also need to be signed with that key.

Comment: Do you have a link to any APKs which demonstrate that? As HefferWolf mentions, that would be a huge security flaw.

Comment: I was more meaning a link to two APKs, first one unmodified and the second one where you've made a clear change and signed with the same META-INF :)  But looking at the ROM and its description, I didn't see any clear mention of modified APKs, only framework JARs (which are unsigned). Though I did see plenty of system APKs that failed a signature check, but I don't have a 3.2 device to hand just now to try and install them.

Answer (score -1):

If You have a root access, then try to back up (for security) old apk and delete it. Then try to copy new one into the same place... I did something like this with Google Maps - custom ROM, couldn't update from Market, I had to do this manually.

Comment: Try to reboot your device... No more ideas, sorry.